# ASP.NET page will not start on IIS7 on Win7 x64

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-7, 64-bit

I try to run a simple "Hello World" ASP.NET web site on my system, but te page does not start (it is not accessible via "localhost/virt_dir/default.aspx"). I have reinstalled framework, run the aspnet_regiis.exe -i command, ....

I don't know where is the problem ... :S

I have been able to publish the same web page on winXP using IIS6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the application mode to classic pipeline. You can do that by clicking on the "Application Pools", finding your application pool and clicking "Basic Settings on the right menu. In the dialog window choose "Classic" option in the "Managed pipeline mode" drop-down.

Also maybe you need to create an entry in your hosts file for your site host name pointing to 127.0.0.1

If this is not the problem, please provide more information like what screen is shown when you try to browse the site and so on.

Comment: It was also problem with services that have to be manually started in win7.

tnx for answer